# sqlite3.InterfaceError and query error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using SQLITE3 in python and I have a couple errors.

First one:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Second one:
This one isn't an ERROR per say, but none the less It doesn't work.

```
username= input("Username: ").lower()
password= input("Password: ")


#Get username and see if it exists
c.execute('SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=?', (username))


print("test")
#Insert values into the account table in the database.
c.execute("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(NULL,?,?)", (username,password))

conn.commit()

#Grab ID
ids = c.execute("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=?", (username,))

#Insert defaults into playlists
c.execute("INSERT INTO playlists VALUES(NULL,?,'NULL')", (ids))

#Save the changes.
conn.commit()
```

All it does is say "Account with that username already exists!" and the only account is

Username: s
Password: s

I've looked around on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything that helped my cause, hence why I'm posting this.
EDIT:

```
   def loggedIn(userid):
        def viewPlaylist(userid):
            print(userid + 1)
            c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM playlists where userid=?", (userid))

            if(c.fetchone): 
                print(c.fetchone)
            else:
                printError("ERROR: No Data found, with that UserID\nCreating Data...")
                c.execute("INSERT INTO playlists VALUES(NULL,?,NULL)", (userid))
                printError("Finished!\nYou may now edit your playlist.")
                loggedIn(userid)
```

Comment: You can use `'SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username={}'.format(username)`

Comment: Doesn't want to work, sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: d
Thinks the username is a column :P

Comment: Where do you make query with this code `c.execute("SELECT * FROM playlists where userid=?", [userid])`? I don't see it in code snippet

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I do not see `SELECT * FROM playlists where userid` in code that you paste. What is type `userid` in code and DB?

Comment: Ah I see my error with that one, let me fix that, but now all that is left is the registration bit.

Comment: Seems that it is still broken, here is what userid should be
c.execute("SELECT id FROM accounts where username=?",(username,)))
Which is parsed as a parameter, to viewPlaylist function.

Comment: The error being it's an unsupported type, I'm guessing that means that it's not an integer which userid should be in the database

Comment: Probably yes. You can check it

Comment: But the Parameter is the ID of the user which is an int and userid is an int so it should be fine?

Comment: print(userid + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'sqlite3.Cursor' and 'int'

Just tried this, that's the error.

Comment: Looks like userid has type `sqlite3.Cursor`. Can you change your code in the question? I mean paste code where you use `c.execute("SELECT * FROM playlists where userid=?", [userid])`

Comment: Check the Original Post

Comment: Try to print type of userid: `print(type(userid))` and give me know what a result do you got

Comment: Yup, <class 'sqlite3.Cursor'>

Comment: Ohm(, where do you call function `loggedIn(userid)`, I mean where do you get userid

Comment: loggedIn(c.execute("SELECT id FROM accounts where username=?",(username)))

Comment: It looks bad, from my side. I will write function in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This from my side:

```
def logged_in(user_name, password):
    # Here you should add conn and cursor, or paste in parameter
    c.execute("SELECT id FROM accounts where username=? and password=?", (user_name, password)))
    user = c.fetchone()
    if user:
        print('logged in')
    else:
        print('user not found')
```

Or in your way, you should make so:

```
loggedIn(c.execute("SELECT id FROM accounts where username=?",(username)).fetchone())
```

Comment: Thanks :)
But what is the problem with the registration ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't see any message with text `Account with that username already exists!` Can you add more code to your question?

Comment: the error is sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: Updated the post, there is no other code but that in the registration.